# vb.net 2010 DataGridView with the text entered in TextBox in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, textbox

i have a `datagridview` and a `textbox` what i need is if the user search a data in `textbox` for example she types "a" all the data that "contains" a in letter it should display in `datagridview`

i tried query

> LIKE @Description '%'

but it typed only the word the contains "a" at the beginning of the sentence
what i need is :
for example
if i type "ginn" should display in `datagridview` "be**ginn**ing"

Answer (score 0):

Before adding value of `textbox` to SqlParameter do next:

```
Dim sqlValue As String = String.Format("%{0}%", textbox.Text)
```

Create `SqlParameter` with new string and then use it in SQL query

```
LIKE @Description
```